# Unable to archive app due to "IPA processing failed", using a .xcframework dependency

Tags: ios13, xcode11, bitcode, xcframework

Unable to archive my app using .xcframework. getting **"IPA processing failed"** error if I select "Rebuild from bitcode" export option while archiving.

Please help me here. Thanks in advance.